# my content is going outside of my div I've tried text align and overflow properties

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.container img {
  vertical-align: center;
}

.container .content {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(2, 2, 2);
  background: rgb(5, 5, 5, 0.5);
  color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6599/ca35b7330ff3ca028be95e4ff1e005ebe822b825_hq.jpg" alt="Bruce Lee" style="width:90%;">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>The Dragon</h2>
    <p>“Forget about winning and losing; forget about pride and pain. Let your opponent graze your skin and you smash into his flesh; let him smash into your flesh and you fracture his bones; let him fracture your bones and you take his life! Do not be concerned
      with escaping safely- lay your life before him!!”.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your content seems to be inside of your container, just at the bottom.

Comment: It doesn't seem as though any heights have been set anywhere so I don't really understand what overflow hidden would do, or which div is overflowing. Can you check the snippet to ensure it definitely shows the problem?

Comment: @A Haworth @sm3sher well it seems to show it correctly in the snippet but on my screen it shows the text going out of the image

Comment: @sm3sher ill post a ss of my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fit the screen, set the min-height of the body to 100vh. If you want the text at the bottom to be at the top, change the order of the html and put the content div over the image.